# Python TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, gurobi

My table has min and a maximum quantity bounds for 10 items. The optimizer should output the best quantities that meet the constraint(total max capacity of 5000 units) and maximize cost savings. if the quantity predicted for an item is above 0 it should be within the maximum and the minimum bounds already set.

Here is the code on the optimizer using the gurobi library in python:

```
%python
import pandas as pd
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import *
from rsecommon.analytics.gurobi import *
try:

    instance = rseenv.RseGurobiEnv.getInstance()
    env = instance.getGurobiEnv()
    
    # Model
    deal = Model("Deal Optimization", env)
    
    # Parameters
    items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7', 'item8', 'item9', 'item10']
    volumes = {'item1':1, 'item2':1, 'item3':2, 'item4':2, 'item5':3, 'item6':3, 'item7':4, 'item8':4, 'item9':5, 'item10':5}
    discounts = {'item1':0.05, 'item2':0.04, 'item3':0.01, 'item4':0.08, 'item5':0.06, 'item6':0.02, 'item7':0.01, 'item8':0.09, 'item9':0.06, 'item10':0.09}
    min_qty = {'item1':540, 'item2':70, 'item3':220, 'item4':170, 'item5':60, 'item6':850, 'item7':910, 'item8':310, 'item9':480, 'item10':60}
    max2_qty = {'item1':540, 'item2':140, 'item3':220, 'item4':340, 'item5':60, 'item6':1700, 'item7':910, 'item8':620, 'item9':480, 'item10':120}

    capacity_cap = 5000

    # Variables
    quantity = deal.addVars(items,lb= 0, ub = {(max2_qty[item] for item in max2_qty)},name='quantity')
    
    # Constraints
    deal.addConstr(((gp.quicksum(volumes[item]*quantity[item] for item in volumes) <= capacity_cap )), name="Capacity")

    # Set objective
    deal.setObjective(quantity.prod(discounts), GRB.MAXIMIZE) 

    # Optimize
    deal.optimize()

    for v in deal.getVars():
        print(v.varName , v.x)
    
    
    print("Optimal Cost Savings:", deal.ObjVal)

except GurobiError as e:
    print('Error code ' + str(e.errno) + ": " + str(e.message))
```

Here is the constraint I was hoping to add but I think my logic is wrong:

```
deal.addConstrs(((gp.quicksum(volumes[item]*quantity[item] for item in volumes) >= min_qty[item] for item in min_qty if item > 0)), "Capacity")
```

The error is:

`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.`

Comment: Can you explain more precisely and succinctly what exactly you want the constraint to do?

Comment: I want the constraint to limit the item quantity between the min qty and max qty if the predicted amount from the optimizer is greater than zero.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on OR Stack Exchange http://or.stackexchange.com